# Geometry Proof Triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles

Show that if two of the corresponding angles of two triangles are equal then so is the third.

Is there a formal way to prove this? I wanted to just say in one sentence that if two angles are the same, then the angles of a triangle must add up to 180, so we are done.

But my professor said that that was insufficient. Please help!

Comment: That sounds sufficient to me...

Comment: I can't think of a more elegant and a sufficient proof than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty much right. To make things slightly more rigorous, suppose that:

> $(1)$ The interior angles of one triangle are $a,b,c$.
>
> $(2)$ The interior angles of the other triangle are $x,y,z$.
>
> $(3)$ We have $a = x$ and $b = y$.

We want to prove that $c = z$. Indeed, observe that from $(1)$, we know that:
$$a+b+c=180^\circ \tag{4}$$
Similarly, we know from $(2)$ that:
$$x + y + z = 180^\circ \tag{5}$$
Hence, it follows that:
\begin{align*}
c &= (a + b + c) - (a + b) \\
&= 180^\circ - (a+b) & \text{by (4)}\\
&= 180^\circ - (x + y) & \text{by (3)}\\
&= (x + y + z) - (x + y) & \text{by (5)}\\
&= z
\end{align*}
as desired.